# Unable to find script library WebUIValidation.js

Tags: asp.net

Hi having some problem with a webserver and some webpages on it, everytime they refresh a popup with this error displays:

Unable to find script library '/aspnet_client/system_web/1_1_4322/WebUIValidation.js'. Try placing the file manually, or reinstall by running 'aspnet_regiis -c'

There are hundreds of answers on google with the following solutions:
1. Run aspnet_regiis -c
2. Replace or copy the file/folders manually

but what to do when the above doens't work.

This webapplication I'm running is using dot.net 1.1 and is located under Default Web Site/App Name/. A aspnet_client directory exist below that virtual directory and contains the WebUIValidation.js file, the aspnet_client directory also lies in the c:\inetpub\wwwroot.

The server is a webserver/sql server, win 2003 IIS 6.
Microsoft dot.net framework 1.1,2.0,3.0,3.5 seems to be installed(Add or Remove programs).
I suspect there is some problem with having all these dot.net version.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem as well. Plenty of posts listed solutions that didn't work for me. What ***did*** work was to check the "Integrated Windows Authentication" on the website node (Right click Web Site -> Properties -> Directory Security) in the IIS 6 manager. It's strange to me that something that had been running fine for years, had this problem all of the sudden.